# How to add prefix/suffix or modify user_agent value of Audit - laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-auditing

Need to add some detail with the user_agent in audit table, sometime need to reduce the length of user_agent. How to configure or override it.

`using - owen-it/laravel-auditing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the class `OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\UserAgentResolver`,

audit.php

```
    'resolver'    => [
       ...
        'user_agent' => App\Resolvers\UserAgentResolver::class,
       ...
    ],
```

App\Resolvers\UserAgentResolver.php

```php
class UserAgentResolver implements \OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\UserAgentResolver
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function resolve()
    {
        return 'Prefix-'.substr(
            Request::header('User-Agent'), 0, 50
        ).'-Suffix';
    }

}
```